# Compute the Patient's Survival Time

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

A patient is diagnosed to have $P_0$ coronavirus at time t = 0 and these viruses grow subsequently according to $\cfrac{dP}{dt} = -\alpha P(M-P)$ where $P(t)$ is the number of cells at time $t$ while $\alpha$ and $M$ are positive constants. The patient will die when the number of bugs approaches infinity. Consider the case $P_0 >M$, find the time the patient has left to live timed from t = 0. Please set $P_0 = 1984$, $M = 1000$, and $\alpha = 1$

My Work: Using $t_c = \cfrac{1}{\alpha M}ln(1-\cfrac {M}{P_0})$

we get
$t_c = \cfrac{1}{1000}ln(1-\cfrac {1000}{1984})$

which equals $-.0007012$ (approximately)

so $t = -0.0007012$ is the survival time of the patient

Now time shouldn't be negative so where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The integral of the differential virus growth equation is:

$t=\frac{ln(1-\frac{M}{P})}{M\alpha}+k$.

By imposing the initial conditions
$P(t=0)=P_{0}$, we get:

$k=-\frac{ln(1-\frac{M}{P_{0}})}{M\alpha}$,

and ultimately

$t=\frac{ln(1-\frac{M}{P})}{M\alpha}-\frac{ln(1-\frac{M}{P_{0}})}{M\alpha}$,

which for P tending to infinity will give the critical time:

$t_{c}=-\frac{ln(1-\frac{M}{P_{0}})}{M\alpha}$.

Substituting the values of $M=$1000, $\alpha=$1, and $P_{0}=$1984, we have:

$t_{c}=-\frac{ln(1-\frac{1000}{1984})}{1000*1}=-\frac{ln(\frac{123}{248})}{1000}≅0.0007012443907$.